# Is there a way to delete first element from map?

Tags: go

Can I delete the first element in map? It is possible with slices `slice = append(slice, slice[1:]...)`, but can I do something like this with maps?

Comment: `for k := range m { delete(m,k); break; }` deletes the "first" element of m for the only valid definition of "first".

Comment: @Volker I think the real issue here is that there is no valid definition of _"first"_ in case of maps. A map being defined by the spec as an _"unordered group of elements"_. That implies that the same code, compiled for different architectures/systems possibly would produce different results, because the underlying implementation might not be exactly the same

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem OP did not ask for a reproducible way to remove a specific element but the "first" and any iteration of a map produces a different "first".

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first element" of an **unordered** collection, which maps are. *Any* definition of "first" referring to map elements is invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maps being hashtables don't have a specified order, so there's no way to delete keys in a defined order, unless you track keys in a separate slice, in the order you're adding them, something like:

```
type orderedMap struct {
    data map[string]int
    keys []string
    mu *sync.RWMutex
}

func (o *orderedMap) Shift() (int, error) {
    o.mu.Lock()
    defer o.mu.Unlock()
    if len(o.keys) == 0 {
        return 0, ErrMapEmpty
    }
    i := o.data[o.keys[0]]
    delete(o.data, o.keys[0])
    o.keys = o.keys[1:]
    return i, nil
}
```

Just to be unequivocal about why you can't really delete the *"first"* element from a map, let me [reference the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types):

> A map is an **unordered** group of elements of one type, called the element type, indexed by a set of unique keys of another type, called the key type. The value of an uninitialized map is nil.

Added the emphasis on the fact that map items are *unordered*

Using a slice to preserve some notion of the order of keys is, fundamentally, flawed, though. Given operations like this:

```
foo := map[string]int{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
}
// a bit later:
foo["foo"] = 3
```

Is the index/key `foo` now updated, or reassigned? Should it be treated as a new entry, appended to the slice if keys, or is it an in-place update? Things get muddled really quickly. The simple fact of the matter is that the map type doesn't contain an *"order"* of things, trying to make it have an order quickly devolves in a labour intensive task where you'll end up writing your own type.

As I said earlier: it's a hashtable. Elements within get reshuffled behind the scenes if the hashing algorithm used for the keys produces collisions, for example. This question has the feel of an X-Y problem: why do you need the values in the map to be ordered? Maybe a map simply isn't the right approach for your particular problem.